# Is it possible to set the unlock passcode with configurator profiles?

Tags: password, apple-configurator, configuration-profiles

I'm managing a half dozen devices with Configurator. I'd like to set the unlock passcode on all of the devices to `friend`. Is this possible using profiles or some other method in Configurator? If so, how?

I can't seem to figure out how, and my Google-Fu isn't giving me answers (too many wifi answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to my knowledge; You can mandate a passcode has to be in use, but you cannot dictate what that passcode is.